# Behind-the-scenes HTTP Request?

Tags: http-api

I'm trying to add a line to my functions.php that does a behind-the-scenes HTTP request submitting some user information to a mailing list URL I have. I'm trying to test the code at the moment, but nothing seems to be working.

I have tried the following:

```
$url = 'blabla.org/mailinglist/add?' . $user_email;
$request = new WP_Http;
$result = $request->request($url);
```

and

```
wp_remote_post($url);
```

Neither have worked. However, if I Just copy and paste the URL into my web browser, it works fine. Please help!

Thanks,

Tre

Comment: What exactly are you trying to send/request?  Do you need to do anything with the response?  When do you want the request fired off?  How do you know it's not working?

Comment: I just want to post information to the URL. I don't want to get the contents or anything like that. But I want it to happen behind the scenes, so the person isn't redirected or anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only use `wp_remote_post()` if you are actually posting something.

Try using `wp_remote_get()` with a full url

```
$url = 'http://blabla.org/mailinglist/add?' . $user_email;
$results = wp_remote_get( $url );
// var_dump( $results );
```

Comment: Make sure to check for `OK` and `200` status with `wp_remote_get_response_code()` and `wp_remote_get_response_message()`. This might not work with every server (some are crappy set up), but in all other cases it's good manner to check if you actually got a valid result.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you're just missing `http://` ?

i.e.

`$url = 'http://blabla.org/mailinglist/add?' . $user_email;`